# how to send message in friends message folder/inbox in facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send message to facebook friend's inbox/message folder from my application using either javascript or php sdk How can I do that?

Before, this we used

```
    FB.api('me/feed', 'post' ......
```

method to post in friends wall from my application but now that method is removed from FEB 2013, I also tried sending mail at

```
    FACEBOOK_FRIENDS_USERNAME@facebook.com
```

but  this method also didn't work all the time some time message was going to others folder in messages but not all the time, Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I rechecked my code, the username was correct to where I was sending the mail.

I have also tried

```
    FB.ui({method : 'send', .....
```

method but it opens one dialog for sending message and then we have to select multiple friends I don't want that, I want to send message to user's facebook friends directly from my application.

If there is some other way to implement this please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send message to a User's friend you can only read User's messages throgh the application ,check this [link](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken). 
But if you still need the functionality to either post on the friend's wall or send message to a User's friend you can use Facebook JavaScript SDK's **share.stream** method

```
<script>
  var share = {
      method: 'stream.share',
      u: 'http://www.fbrell.com/'
  };

 FB.ui(share, Log.info.bind('stream.share callback'));
</script>
```

or you can utilize [**Send Dialog**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)